# Why when I don't use the "lambda method reference" code style in static block will cause deadlock?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, jvm, jvm-crash

PS: Sorry for my poor english.I can't describe the problem clearly.
:(

When I don't use the "lambda method reference" code style in the static block, like:

```
static{
map.keySet().parallelStream().forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
        });
}
```

then the program running forever, never stop.

But when I change the code to

```
static{
map.keySet().parallelStream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

then the bug gone.The program can finish immediately.

Just look directly at the code please, I already tried to simplify the code as far as I can.

```
public class BugSimulate {

    static {
        init();
    }

    private static void init() {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        int i = 0;
        map.put(++i, "1");
        map.put(++i, "1");
        map.put(++i, "1");
        map.put(++i, "1");
        map.put(++i, "1");
        map.put(++i, "1");
        map.put(++i, "1");
        map.put(++i, "1");
        map.put(++i, "1");

        // running forever
        map.keySet().parallelStream().forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
        });

        // finish immediately
        //        map.keySet().parallelStream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        new BugSimulate();
    }
}
```

[image]

but when I change the lambda code

```
e -> {System.out.println(e);}
```

to

```
System.out::println
```

the program finish immediately

[image]

Or I change parallelStream() to normal stream(),Bugs gone.

Or I remove the static blocks,Bugs gone too.

My jdk version is 1.8.0_202

And the OS version is MacOS 10.14.5

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? What kind of unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: @Eran Very very sorry for that.I reedit my description just now.Please read again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Interesting Question**: This question is similar with [Class Loading with Static Block Competition Cause Deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517964/program-hangs-if-thread-is-created-in-static-initializer-block),

but for this issue, it's caused by when use `e -> {System.out.println(e);}` after **compiling**, it will generate an **synthetic method: anonymous static private method** for this, as:

```
  // access flags 0x100A
  private static synthetic lambda$init$0(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 27 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 28 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE e Ljava/lang/Integer; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

this **synthetic method: private static method** is generated by `e -> {System.out.println(e);}` compile.

also it's similar equal to:

```
static {
    init();
}

private static void init() {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    int i = 0;
    map.put(++i, "1");
    ***
    Thread foo = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            print(map.keySet().iterator().next()); //try access the private method, this cause a competition with **Class Initializer** and **static block**
        }
    };

    foo.start();
    try {
        foo.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//equal to e -> {System.out.println(e);}
private static void print(int t) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

so as [Class Loading with Static Block Competition Cause Deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517964/program-hangs-if-thread-is-created-in-static-initializer-block) this post explanation: when init class **BugSimulate**, it will invoke `static block` firstly, but since it's using **parallelStream** and try to invoke the generated private anonymous method, this caused an competition with **class initializer**, so finally it's deadlock.

[image: Competition]

Comment: That's interesting. I have run the "bug" code and it worked without deadlock. And why this variant works correctly `System.out::println`?

Comment: @v.ladynev when use `System.out::println` will invoke this static method directly: `GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;`

Comment: Thanks a lot,Now I understand.The **anonymous method in lambda** will generate at runtime,But **normal anonymous method** generated at compile time.Thats the very important point which I don't know and then caused my confusion

Comment: @ACBingo but it’s worth mentioning that you should not rely on subtle implementation details, e.g. while `Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "d").parallel().forEach(System.out::println);` does not deadlock, because it creates a direct delegate, `Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "d").parallel().forEach(System.out::printf);` may deadlock, as it will invoke a synthetic method of your class like a lambda expression, to prepare the array for the varargs invocation. The takeaway of the linked Q&As is that you should avoid multi-threaded operations in class initializers in general.

Comment: @Holger,Thanks a lot!So the 'printf’ method will invoke a synthetic method, which means it also will generate some anonymous class (or method) at running time too? In the end,will caused an competition with class initializer

Comment: @ACBingo the synthetic method is generated at compile-time. The class implementing the functional interface will be generated at runtime. There will always be a runtime generated class, but for certain method references, it will invoke the target method directly. In contrast, for lambda expressions and certain nontrivial method references (varargs, intersection types, special access modifiers), it will invoke a compiler generated method in your class, which can cause these deadlocks.